# how to extract values ​from a dictionary in the rows for the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I tried in several ways to extract the data from the adress column and transform it into new columns

```
 df.head(3)

       name    Adress

0      Joan   {'city': 'Rio', 'district': 'Leme'}

1      Joan   {'city': 'Sao Paulo', 'district': 'Bras'}

2   Vincent   {'city': 'Recife', 'district': 'Caxanga'}
```

I used all of these methods but none worked

```
#reduce(set.union, df_apresentar['address'], set())

#set(df_apresentar['address'].values())

#values = set(df_apresentar['address'][0])

#df_apresentar['endereco'] = df_apresentar.address.apply (lambda x: x.get ('address'))

#df_apresentar['endereco'] = df_apresentar.address.apply (lambda x: x.get ('value'))
```

I need something like that:

```
df.head(3)

       name    Adress  city     district

0      Joan   {}       Rio      Leme

1      Joan   {}      Friburgo  Bras

2   Vincent   {}      Recife    Caxanga
```

Comment: please post `df.head(3).to_dict()` for easier replication

Comment: what is the output of `type(df.loc[0,'Adress'])`?

Comment: You could access them individually, using pandas `str` methods: ``df.assign(city = df.Adress.str.get('city'), district = df.Adress.str.get('district'))``

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See this **:** 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235  for a full explanation.

Comment: The output for  `set(df['address'][0])` is a `str` but when i use `df.assign(city = df.address.str.get('city'), district = df.address.str.get('district'))` return `NaN`

Comment: `address` or `adress` (single `d`) ?   You used single d in sample data.

Comment: in the example above there is only one `d`, but in my study it is with 2 `d`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply(pd.Series)` to turn the address column dicts into their own columns, and concatenate that back in with the original `df`:

```
address_df = df.pop("Address")
new_df = pd.concat([df, address_df.apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1)

      name       city district
0     Joan        Rio     Leme
1     Joan  Sao Paulo     Bras
2  Vincent     Recife  Caxamga
```

Or, as a slight variation, use `join` instead of `concat`

```
new_df = df.drop("Address",axis=1).join(df.Address.apply(pd.Series))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Dataframe()` method and `tolist()` method:

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame(data=df['Adress'].tolist())
```

Finally use `concat()` method:

```
newdf=pd.concat((df,newdf),axis=1)
```

Now If you print `newdf` you will get:

```
    name      Adress                                        city        district
0   Joan      {'city': 'Rio', 'district': 'Leme'}           Rio         Leme
1   Joan      {'city': 'Sao Paulo', 'district': 'Bras'}     Sao Paulo   Bras
2   Vincent   {'city': 'Recife', 'district': 'Caxanga'}     Recife      Caxanga
```

If needed use `drop()` method:

```
newdf=newdf.drop(columns=['Adress'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to expand the json/dict into columns and then use [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate back to the original dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df.drop(columns='Adress'),  pd.json_normalize(df['Adress'])], axis=1) 


      name       city district
0     Joan        Rio     Leme
1     Joan  Sao Paulo     Bras
2  Vincent     Recife  Caxanga
```

Note that using `pd.json_normalize()` to expand the json/dict to columns is far more performance efficient than using .apply(pd.Series()) to expand.

Comment: `out = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('Adress'))` pop helps removing the drop if not making a copy of course :)

Comment: @anky Nice suggestion! :-)